# Ошибка при работе с элементами массива: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, массивы

При работе с элементами массива возникает ошибка компиляции:

```
error: invalid types 'float*[float]' for array subscript
```

Выжимка из кода:

```
float decide(float x, float y);

int main()
{
    float *arr = new float[cy * cx];
    int i;
    float r, w;
    ...
    arr[i] = decide(arr[w], arr[r]); // ошибка
    ...
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте всё же привести код к виду [mcve] без лишнего мусора.

Comment: Ну а по самой ошибке, для индексации массива очевидно должен использоваться целый тип, а не вещественный.

Comment: Сделал это за вас, Екатерина Евгеньевна.

Answer (score 1):

Для индексации массива нужно использовать целочисленный тип, а не вещественный.

В разных компиляторах такая ошибка диагностируется с различными сообщениями:

- Clang:

  ```
  error: array subscript is not an integer
  ```
- GCC:

  ```
  invalid types 'int [N][double]' for array subscript
  ```
- MSVC:

  ```
  error C2108: subscript is not of integral type`
  ```

Если возникает необходимость опираться на значение вещественной переменной в качестве индекса массива, то такое значение нужно так или иначе привести к целочисленному. Самый простой вариант использовать приведение типа, например:

```
arr[static_cast<int>(w)]
```

Или другие более подходящие под задачу варианты, в частности округление через [`std::lround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) и т.д.